# Mysql remove duplicate entries from table

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

I am having a table with the following columns

```
code  (varchar)
desc  (varchar)
attr1 (varchar)
attr2 (varchar)
attr3 (varchar)
reference
```

And the table contains bulk data.What i need is that i need to remove all entries from the table having duplicate values for code,attr1,attr2,attr3.I tried with adding unique index using these columns but didn't worked.Can i use some script for these.All these columns allows null values.my database engine is myisam.

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word in mysql.Dont use it as column name.It will lead to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique index and drop the duplicates with

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table
ADD UNIQUE INDEX dup_idx (code, attr1, attr2, attr3);
```

Comment: I tried using that.But didnt worked.Is it because of my table having data with null values.?

Comment: Did you try alter **ignore** table?

Comment: Yes i do.Because i have seen the same answer you have posted and tried like that.But it didnt helped me

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE a 
FROM your_table a 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, code, attr1, attr2, attr3 
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY code, attr1, attr2, attr3
) b 
ON a.id = b.id 
AND a.code = b.code 
AND a.attr1 = b.attr1 
AND a.attr2 = b.attr2 
AND a.attr3 = b.attr3 
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UniqueData` (`code`, `attr1` , `attr2` ,`attr3`) ;
```

This should actually work but, it will not bother to delete or change the older data.
It will make sure that the future data will be unique.

If you try to add a duplicate entry then it will throw an error.

If you still can't get the solution while using this, share the error message you are getting.

Comment: i dont get any error message when i try to add the index.And the index is created but it doesnt remove any duplicate entry from the data but it throws error if i try to add a new duplicate entry.